# Spring autowired is null

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a simple code to understand Spring DI functionality.

Here is my code in `tester.java`:

```java
package com.email;

@Component
public class Tester {

    @Autowired
    private static EmailService emailService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        System.out.println("emailService: " + emailService); // is null
    }
}

interface EmailService {
    String sayHello();
}

@Component
class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

And here is in `spring-config.xml`:

```xml
<bean id="emailService" class="com.email.EmailServiceImpl"/>
   <context:annotation-config/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.email"/>
```

I declared the `emailService` bean which refers to `EmailServiceImpl` class , why i get `null` in `emailService` ?

Comment: This is because annotation doesn't work.

Comment: @RomanC Why? i activated it in `xml` file.

Comment: @RomanC I get this warning: `Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static com.email.EmailService com.email.Tester.emailService`

Comment: @RomanC I made `emailService` static to be able to test it in main method, what is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotation doesn't work because the field is `static`. Change it to

```
@Autowired
private EmailService emailService;
```

Comment: So how i test it in the `main` method?

Comment: The simple way is to use `ctx.getBean()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the field you are trying to set by autowiring is declared as static.  It really doesn't make sense to use dependency injection on a static field from a design perspective, but if you must, you can use a setter method.

```
@Autowired
void setEmailService (EmailService emailService) {
  Tester.emailService = emailService;
}
```